# Making asynchronous calls through Mongoid using Sidekiq and Kiqstand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, asynchronous, sidekiq

The combination of using both [Mongoid](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid) and [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) has recently been made possible because of [Kiqstand](https://github.com/mongoid/kiqstand). Does anyone know how to use Kiqstand to make asynchronous calls through Mongoid?

Answer (score 4):

Did you see [Mongoid: Tips and FAQs: Sidekiq](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#sidekiq)? I think it has the answer you seek:

> When you intialize Sidekiq, add the middleware to the Kiqstand server stack.

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Kiqstand::Middleware
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly does this mean, and where in rails app should this be done?

Comment: @Jan: In a Rails app, I recommend adding the above block to `#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`. For more on what you might want to put in that file, see the [Sidekiq Advanced Options](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options) documentation page.

Comment: there is no mention on the Sidekiq page (anymore?) on how to configure Sidekiq with MongoDB backend.   Can someone add to the answer and provide configuration details, or a URL?